# How to display 'auto_now_add' fields in django forms?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I wish to know how to display 'auto_now_add' fields (and as disabled fields) in django frontend forms.
I attach some of relevant code:

```
# models.py
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100)
    inserted = models.DateTimeField('Inserted ', auto_now_add=True)

# forms.py
class ProcessModelAForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            "name": forms.TextInput({
                "class": "form-control",
                "disabled": True,
            }),
            "inserted": forms.DateTimeInput({
                "class": "form-control",
                "disabled": True,
            }),
        }

# views.py
def process_model_a(request, pk):
    instance_model_a = get_object_or_404(ModelA, id=pk)
    process_form = ProcessModelAForm(instance=instance_model_a)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # ...
    return render(request, 'myapp/process_model_a.html', {'process_form ': process_form , 'instance':instance_model_a , } )

# process_model_a.html
  <form method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in process_form %}
    <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{field.label}}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            {{ field }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        {{ field.errors }}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg center-block">Process</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

The page "process_model_a.html" shows only "name" fields.
How can I display also "inserted" field?
Thanks.

Comment: `auto_now_add` automatically implies `editable=False`, which means that the field is not included in `__all__`. You could try to explicitly add the field in the model class, or set the model field as editable. I don't really recommend overriding the default, though. A field that is not meant to be updated by the user doesn't belong in the form. Instead you can access the form instance in the template, and access the values like this: `{{ process_form.instance.inserted }}` and display the creation time as plain text instead of as a disabled form widget.

Comment: Hi @HåkenLid and thanks for your answer. I wish to show also non-editable fields as summary for inserted data instead of showing that field as a plain text

Comment: ModelFields with the attribute `editable=False` will not be included in a `ModelForm`. You probably have to write your own custom `ModelForm`, or a custom `DateTimeField` to override this.